# Highcharts.js doesn't show lines of chart when is printed

Tags: javascript, .net, highcharts

I'm trying to print an html page by a .net library called HiQPdf but something goes wrong and my pdf file shows like this:
[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/va4Wo.png)

Html code:
https://pastebin.com/L4YcWzuM

```
<td colspan="2">
  <div id="containerPUN"></div>
</td>
Highcharts.chart('containerPUN', {
                            title: {
                                text: 'Andamento Indice PUN'
                            },
                            xAxis: {
                                categories: ascisse,
                                labels: {
                                    rotation: 0
                                }
                            },
                            series: [{
                                name: 'Valori',
                                data: <%=datiAndamentoPun %>
                            }]
                        });
```

ps. This is my first post so be lenient.

Comment: pps: in html it shows properly, doesn't work only when try to get pdf from html

Comment: There is no export option to generate an image/pdf from the wrapper.
The only way to have a picture of the graph on the backend is to [set up the server's](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export- ... serverside) Node and execute the command.

Comment: Here's the answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65670718/hiqpdf-isnt-rendering-chart-js-chart-on-pdf?noredirect=1&lq=1